# Store different data for the same cells range based on ComboBox Dropdown options. Each option storing different data for range C5:AG24

Tags: excel

I have a Combobox Dropdown with 12 options(Months of the year). I have C5:AG24 with normal dropdown with 7 text options. I want that every time I select an option from the combobox, C5:AG24 to have their own data and to be stored.

Example: If I select Option 1 from the combobox(January), then I select "TBD" from the normal dropdown list in C5 and then select Option 2 from the combobox(February), I want C5 to not show any data, so I can select for example "PL". Finally, if I move back to Option 1 from the combobox(January), still C5 is "TBD".

Basically have different databases for C5:AG24 depending on ComboBox Dropdown options.

How can I achieve this? I have been struggling a lot.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I tried to checked online, but failed.